# How do I close a connection to a Cassandra cluster in the Astyanax API?

Tags: cassandra, database-connection, astyanax

I am newbie for sever side development and I know its good practice to close database connections. But I couldn't find anything on the getting started documentation for Astyanax Client.

Does the client manages the connections on its own?

I have been running netstat command for 9160 and the connections are not getting closed even after CRUD operations are finished.

Note: When I run junit tests, connections are getting closed, but they wont be closed when I send requests from chrome, SOAP-UI or LOAD-UI

Answer (score 1):

Check AstyanaxContext,  from there you can close the connection

```
context.shutdown();
```